# Scraped data using BeautifulSoup appears as code in excel

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I made this Python script for web scraping and below is my full code. I scraped that data to an Excel sheet, but it appears as an code line including the data. I want like this:

[the scraped data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJKG7.png)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
result = requests.get('https://www.olx.com.eg/en/ads/q-%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9/')
time.sleep(4)
src = result.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

titles = []
prices = []
PH_area = []
location = []
posted = []
payment = []

titles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'a5112ca8'})
prices = soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_52497c97'})
PH_area = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'a8f6df88'})
location = soup.find_all('span', {'class': '_424bf2a8'})
posted = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'_2e28a695'})

for i in range(len(titles)):
    titles.append(titles[i].text.strip())
#links.append(titles[i].find('a').attrs['href'])
    prices.append(titles[i].text.strip())

    PH_area.append(titles[i].text.strip())
    location.append(titles[i].text.strip())
    posted.append(titles[i].text.strip())
    df = pd.DataFrame(zip(titles,prices,PH_area,location,posted),columns=['Title','Price','Area','Location','Posted'])
df.to_excel(r"D:\Python\Unfinished projects\Olx\Olx Scrapping.xlsx",index=False)
```

what should I do please

Answer (score 2):

I made the change in the loop where we are iterating over the `title_tags, price_tags, PH_area_tags, location_tags, and posted_tags.` Instead of appending the whole tag to the respective list, I am now appending only the text content of the tag using the `.text` attribute of the BeautifulSoup object.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

result = requests.get('https://www.olx.com.eg/en/ads/q-%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9/')
time.sleep(4)
src = result.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

titles = []
prices = []
PH_area = []
location = []
posted = []

title_tags = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'a5112ca8'})
price_tags = soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_52497c97'})
PH_area_tags = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'a8f6df88'})
location_tags = soup.find_all('span', {'class': '_424bf2a8'})
posted_tags = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'_2e28a695'})

for title_tag, price_tag, PH_area_tag, location_tag, posted_tag in zip(title_tags, price_tags, PH_area_tags, location_tags, posted_tags):
    titles.append(title_tag.text.strip())
    prices.append(price_tag.text.strip())
    PH_area.append(PH_area_tag.text.strip())
    location.append(location_tag.text.strip())
    posted.append(posted_tag.text.strip())

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(titles,prices,PH_area,location,posted),columns=['Title','Price','Area','Location','Posted'])
df.to_excel(r"Olx Scrapping.xlsx",index=False)
```

Generates the output like this:

[image: Extracted Data Result]